# Does the ,remove_hiberfile tag disable hibernate when I boot into Windows?

Tags: dual-boot, mount, windows, hibernate, windows-10

From what I understand, it deletes the hibernation file to allow mounting the ntfs drive. However, if I have hibernate enabled in Windows, will the hibernate file be generated again allowing me to hibernate? And if I disable "Mount at startup" (,noauto tag), will that only delete the hiberfil.sys file when I mount the drive by clicking it rather than doing it at every boot up? What's the disadvantage of this?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, it deletes the hibernation file to allow mounting the ntfs drive. However, if I have hibernate enabled in Windows, will the hibernate file be generated again allowing me to hibernate?

Yes.

And if I disable "Mount at startup" (,noauto tag), will that only delete the hiberfil.sys file when I mount the drive by clicking it rather than doing it at every boot up?

Yes.

What's the disadvantage of this?

None.